# Saving data of a html table in mysql table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

In my system user will see a basic timetable view and he can add subjects by using a dropdown in each list.I need to store all the subjects in the timetable in a sql table. when a user selects a subject using a dropdown a new sql row should be created with start,end time,day and subject_code.Can someone please help

Add Time Table view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/timeTableMapping.css" th:href="@{/css/timeTableMapping.css}">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Time Table</title>
</head>
<body>



</form>
<div class="container2">
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/timeTableMapping/save}" th:object="${timeTableMapping}" method="post">
        <table border="0" cell[adding="10">
            <tr>
                <td><h1>Time Table:</h1></td>
                <td>
                    <select th:field="*{time_table_code}">
                        <option value="">Choose..</option>
                        <option th:each="timeTable: ${timeTables}" th:value="${timeTable.name}" th:text="${timeTable.name}"/>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table border="1" >
            <thead>
            <tr>
            </tr>
            <br>
            <th></th>
            <th:block th:each="day : ${days}">
                <th th:text="${day.name}"></th>
            </th:block>


            </thead>
            <tbody>


            <th:block th:each="time : ${times}">
                <tr>

                    <th th:text="${ time.start }+':00 - ' + ${ time.end }+':00'"></th>

                    <th:block th:each="day : ${days}">
                        <td>
                            <select th:field="*{subject_code}">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option th:each="subject: ${subjects}" th:value="${subject.subject_code}" th:text="${subject.name}"/>

                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </th:block>


                </tr>
            </th:block>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <button type="submit">Save</button>

                </td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class TimeTableMappingController {
    @Autowired
    private  TimeTableMappingDAO timeTableMappingDAO;

    @Autowired
    private TimeTableDAO timeTableDAO;

    @Autowired
    private SubjectDAO subjectDAO;

    @Autowired
    private StudentGroupDAO studentGroupDAO;

    @Autowired
    private DayDAO dayDAO;

    @Autowired
    private TimeDAO timeDAO;


    @RequestMapping("/timeTableMapping")
    public String viewHomePage(Model model){
        List<TimeTableMapping> timeTableMappingDetails= timeTableMappingDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("timeTableMappingDetails",timeTableMappingDetails);
        return "timeTableMapping";
    }



    @RequestMapping("/timeTableMapping/new")
    public String addTimeTableMapping(Model model){
        TimeTableMapping timeTableMapping =new TimeTableMapping();
        model.addAttribute("timeTableMapping",timeTableMapping);

        List<TimeTable> timeTableDetail = timeTableDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("timeTables", timeTableDetail);

        List<Subject> subjectDetail = subjectDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("subjects", subjectDetail);

        List<Day> dayDetails = dayDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("days",dayDetails);

        List<Time> timeDetails = timeDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("times",timeDetails);

        return "addTimeTableMapping";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/timeTableMapping/save",method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveTimeTable(@ModelAttribute("timeTableMapping") TimeTableMapping timeTableMapping){
        timeTableMappingDAO.save(timeTableMapping);
        return  "redirect:/timeTableMapping";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/timeTableMapping/saveAll",method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveAll(@ModelAttribute("timeTable") TimeTable timeTable){
        timeTableDAO.saveAll(timeTable);
        return  "redirect:/timeTable";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/timeTableMapping/edit/{id}")
    public ModelAndView updateTimeTable(@PathVariable(name="id")Long id){
        ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView(("updateTimeTable"));

        TimeTable timeTable = timeTableDAO.findById(id);
        mav.addObject("timeTable",timeTable);

        List<Subject> subjectDetails = subjectDAO.findAll();
        mav.addObject("subjects", subjectDetails);

        List<StudentGroup> studentGroupDetails = studentGroupDAO.findAll();
        mav.addObject("studentGroups",studentGroupDetails);

        List<Day> dayDetails = dayDAO.findAll();
        mav.addObject("days",dayDetails);

        List<Time> timeDetails = timeDAO.findAll();
        mav.addObject("times",timeDetails);

        return  mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/timeTableMapping/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable(name="id") Long id){
        timeTableDAO.delete(id);
        return  "redirect:/timeTable";
    }
}
```

I tried to do this but it seems what happens is trying to save all the data in the timeTable view in the same SQL record. And because of it, an error message occurs.

**Exception:**

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not execute batch; SQL [insert into timetablemappings (day, end, start, subject_code, time_table_code, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute batch
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute batch; SQL [insert into timetablemappings (day, end, start, subject_code, time_table_code, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute batch
```

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'subject_code' at row 1
```

Comment: so, check the max length you can have in column subject_code, and then check the length of the input. that should give you a clear idea of what is going wrong

Comment: when i only select one subject it works properly. But when i select more than 1 it shows this error message

Comment: *Data truncation: Data too long for column 'subject_code'*  - the data that you are trying to insert is longer than the field is able to store.  Check its defintion in the DB

Comment: i need to add a uniquesql record for all the subjects i select. (ex:50 records if 10 time slots and 5 days).But problem is when i try this all the records are added to the same row

Comment: This is the sql statement generated when i try this and it is generated once at when i select submit button but i want to generate this statement everytime i select a subject                                                
 SQL [insert into timetablemappings (day, end, start, subject_code, time_table_code, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)];